# Cannot recreate JSON value from JSON in string format

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I have the following object:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public object TestValue { get; set; }
}
```

My database contains strings in JSON format e.g.

```
string dbValue1 = "[\"test value\"]"
string dbValue2 = "[\"one value\",[\"another value|or this value\"]]"
int dbValue3 = 1
bool dbValue4 = true
```

And I need to deserialize these values to the `TestModel.TestValue` property so that when I serialize the object I get the same format that is stored in the database. I can obviously get an `int` or `bool` an a basic array to work, but I can't in the case of a slightly more complex array. From the `dbValue2` above I would want the output to be:

```
"testValue" : ["one value",["another value|or this value"]]
```

Now, I am using ServiceStack.Text and so far this is what I've tried:

```
TestValue = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(dbValue, typeof(object))
TestValue = dbValue.FromJson<object>()
TestValue = JsonObject.Parse(dbValue)
```

And these generate:

```
"testValue":"[one value,[another value|or this value]]"
"testValue":{"one value":["another value|or this value"]}
"testValue":{"one value":["another value|or this value"]}
```

I can understand why these would not work, but I can't figure out how to do what I need.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the root element is an array in the JSON. ServiceStack seems to choke on that.

If you try it with ServiceStack and add a root object with the same array as a property e.g.

```
var json = "{\"root\":[\"one value\",[\"another value|or this value\"]]}";
var testValue = JsonObject.Parse(json);
Console.WriteLine(testValue.ToJson());
```

It serializes the array correctly.

[Json.Net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) seems to just work though.

```
var json = "[\"one value\",[\"another value|or this value\"]]";            
var testValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testValue));
```

Annoying :)

Comment: I have edited the question so hopefully it is a little clearer, but yes each value is in a different row.

Comment: I have added a solution (kind of) ;-)

Comment: Hey sir, yes I've tried that too - great minds eh? The issue then is `testValue` contains a key-value pair. So if I then set my model property with `testValue`, when my model property is serialized I get the root object and not just the value in the JSON. If I try an extract the value from the key-value pair, it all goes wrong again!

Comment: What about with JSON.NET seems to work when doing    `var model = new TestModel();

            model.TestValue = testValue;

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));` or am I missing something?

Comment: The entire application is based around JSON so I am reluctant to replace the serializer as there are a few custom features. It would mean quite a bit of re-testing.